# How to shuffle 2 different text file into 1?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char temp[64];
    FILE *fp1=fopen("data/1.txt","a");
    FILE *fp2=fopen("data/2.txt","r");
    
    while(fgets(temp,64,fp2)!=NULL){
        fputs(temp,fp1);
    }
    
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

With such code I was able to combine 2 different text file into 1.

```
data/1.txt contents: abcdefghijk
data/2.txt contents: ABCDE
Outcome: abcdefghijkABCDE
```

However, I am struggling with shuffling 2 different text file.

```
Wanted result: aAbBcCdDeEfghijk
```

Followings are my current code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp_out;
    char ch1,ch2;

    int result=1;
    fp1=fopen("data/1.txt","r");
    fp2=fopen("data/2.txt","r");
    fp_out=fopen("data/out.txt","w");

//shuffling code area//

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp_out);

    char buf[64]={};
    fp_out=fopen("data/out.txt","r");
    fgets(buf,64,fp_out);

    if(!strncmp("aAbBcCdDeEfghijk",buf,64))
        printf("PASS\n");
    else
        printf("FAIL\n");

    fclose(fp_out);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I design a code in "shuffling code area" in order to have outcomes like wanted result? I have thought about making 2 different FOR loops and combining but it kept showed an error.

Comment: First, that doesn't appear to be a shuffle, as much as an *interleave*.  That said, consider how you could use `fgetc` rather than `fgets` to accomplish what you seem to desire.

Comment: @Power of Knowledge I has created a simply code to that! Hope that works for you! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

This is some dirty way to do the job.

You can read the file which ever you want to write first character first and then read a character from second file and write both into third file one after the other.

Just adding extra code as per your need.

This just works for your case , not tested with many cases and corner cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp_out;
    char ch1,ch2;

    int result=1;
    
    int file1_content_over = 0;
    int file2_content_over = 0;
    
    fp1 = fopen("data/1.txt","r");
    fp2 = fopen("data/2.txt","r");
    fp_out=fopen("data/out.txt","w");

    //shuffling code area//

    // read till file1_content_over or file2_content_over is not finished
    while(! file1_content_over || !file2_content_over)
    {
        ch1 = fgetc(fp1);
        ch2 = fgetc(fp2);
        
        if(ch1 != EOF)
            fputc(ch1,fp_out);
        else
            file1_content_over = 1;

        if(ch2 != EOF)
            fputc(ch2,fp_out);
        else 
            file2_content_over = 1;
    }
    
    //shuffling code area//
    
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp_out);
    
    char buf[64]={};
    fp_out=fopen("data/out.txt","r");
    fgets(buf,64,fp_out);
    printf("buf = %s\n", buf);

    if(!strncmp("aAbBcCdDeEfghijk",buf,strlen("aAbBcCdDeEfghijk")))
        printf("PASS\n");
    else
        printf("FAIL\n");

    fclose(fp_out);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for me! Not the best optimized code, I didnt get to much time to that!

**Main():**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

int removingSPaces(char array[MAX], int sizeArray);
void orderChar(char bufFile1[MAX], char bufFile2[MAX], char bufOut[MAX], int maxSize, int sizeBuf1, int sizeBuf2);
int getChar(char buf[MAX], FILE *fp);

int main(){
    FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fpOut;
    char bufFile1[MAX] = {0}, bufFile2[MAX] = {0}, bufOut[MAX] = {0};
    int sizeBuf1 = 0, sizeBuf2 = 0;
    int maxSize=0;

    if((fp1=fopen("file1.txt","r")) == NULL || (fp2=fopen("file2.txt","r")) == NULL || (fpOut=fopen("fileOut.txt","w")) == NULL){
        perror("");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    sizeBuf1 = getChar(bufFile1, fp1); //geting the chars from file1
    fclose(fp1);

    sizeBuf1 = removingSPaces(bufFile1, sizeBuf1); //removing the \n if exists from chars of file1

    sizeBuf2 = getChar(bufFile2, fp2); //geting the chars from file2
    fclose(fp2);

    sizeBuf2 = removingSPaces(bufFile2, sizeBuf2); //removing the \n if exists from chars of file2

    maxSize = sizeBuf1 + sizeBuf2; //Max Size to loop for

    orderChar(bufFile1, bufFile2, bufOut, maxSize, sizeBuf1, sizeBuf2); //Order the chars!

    fprintf(fpOut, "%s", bufOut); //Printing to the file

    fclose(fpOut);


/* COPIED FROM YOUR CODE */
    char buf[64]={0}; //Just added the 0, because you cant initialize the array like with only {} 
    
    if((fpOut=fopen("fileOut.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        perror("");
        exit(1);
    }

    fgets(buf,64, fpOut);

    if(!strncmp("aAbBcCdDeEfghijk", buf, 64))
        printf("PASS\n");
    else
        printf("FAIL\n");

    fclose(fpOut);
/* COPIED FROM YOUR CODE */

    return 0;
}
```

**Functions():**

```
int removingSPaces(char array[MAX], int sizeArray){

    int size = sizeArray;

    if(array[sizeArray -1] == '\n'){
        array[sizeArray -1] = '\0';
        size = strlen(array);
    }
    return size;
}

int getChar(char buf[MAX], FILE *fp){
    char bufAux[MAX];
    int size;
    
    while(fgets(bufAux, sizeof(bufAux), fp)){
        size = strlen(bufAux);  
    }

    strcpy(buf, bufAux);
    return size; 
}

void orderChar(char bufFile1[MAX], char bufFile2[MAX], char bufOut[MAX], int maxSize, int sizeBuf1, int sizeBuf2){
    int positionsF1=0, positionsF2=0;
    int aux = 0; //This will starts organization by the first file! If you want to change it just change to 1;

    for(int i=0; i < maxSize; i++){
        if(aux == 0 && positionsF1 != sizeBuf1){ 
            bufOut[i]=bufFile1[positionsF1];
            if(positionsF2!=sizeBuf2){
                aux = 1;
            }
            positionsF1++;
        }else if(aux == 1 && positionsF2 != sizeBuf2){
            bufOut[i]=bufFile2[positionsF2];
            if(positionsF1!=sizeBuf1){
                aux = 0;
            }
            positionsF2++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Content of file 1:**

```
abcdefghijk
```

**Content of file 2:**

```
ABCDE
```